# Spliting string into 3 parts

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to learn to split strings.  I have a string, for example, `Adams, John - 22.6.2001`.  What is the easiest way to split each of the following pieces of information into particular strings?  I need the name, surname, and date.

This is the solution that I tried myself:

```
string st = "Adams, John - 22.6.2001"
st = st.Trim(); // To replace all possible white spaces? But I don't know how can I cut each of details into string.
```

Comment: That's not trimming, that's parsing.  Parsing names is extraordinarly difficult, if not impossible, given that some people have multi-word names as either first, middle, or last names, so you can't tell in complex cases which it is.

Comment: What about for 3-word name?

Comment: And don't forget those languages that put the surname before the given name!

Comment: Why so many edit ? Lost the meaning of this question...

Comment: @Servy I just wanted to correct the wording `trim` to `split`. Sorry for that.

Comment: I highly recommend the OP should delete this question because it's too broad, unless you restrict your input string to some **exact** format.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for informing me about that. I tried to edit the input string so it will have some more meaningful format.

Comment: @Marek, so you will just have First Name and Last Name, What about multiple names ?

Comment: @Habib well I hope there is an option to use some kind of `separator`, isn`t it ?

Comment: @Marek, You string should be in some consistent format, like names separated by `,` and names and date separated by `-`. e.g. `st = "Adams, John, Bryan - 22.6.2001"`. Where names are in order of First, Middle, Last. Something like that but **consistent**

Comment: @Habib, May I ask what would happen if the string would be st = "Adams, John Quincy - 22.6.2001"; is there any way to handle that?

Comment: @Marek, what would be the rule then ? Adams as First Name, John Quincy as Last Name or, Adams as Last name, Quincy as Middle, and John as First, What ever it is you can use `string.Split` and get the names as per your own rules. You can't have a generic name parser.

Comment: What about people who [don't have surnames](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using String.Split() to break the parts of the string into a string array. Trim() is used to remove white-space from the start and end of a string, so this can be used to tidy up the resulting strings.

```
string st = "Adams, John - 22.6.2001";

// first split on dash, to seperate name and date
string[] partsArray = st.Split('-');

// now split first part to get first and surname (trim surrounding whitespace)
string[] nameArray = partsArray[0].Split(',');
string firstName = nameArray[1].Trim();
string lastName = nameArray[0].Trim();

// get date from other part (again trim whitespace)
string dateAsString = partsArray[1].Trim();
```

Parsing text is a complex topic, but I think the question was just looking for an introduction. There are many edge cases and issues which you'd need to add to a parser to get close to 100% results for different name and date formats. If you were importing data like this in bulk, you would use a CSV file or similar to break up the parts before importing.

Answer (score 4):

> what is the easiest way to trim each of these information into
>   particular strings: name, surname, date ?

Looks like you want to **split sting** based on `,` and space.

```
string[] splitArray = st.Split(new string[] { ",", " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**EDIT:**

As far as parsing names is concerned, you have to define some kind of rules that how your string would have names. For example your string could have multiple names, First, Last, Middle separated by commas, in that case the above statement will not give you the result that you need. You have to define some rules to make your input string consistent, and based on that you can use `string.Split` to get values.

Comment: That works for some of the simple examples, but not more complex ones.  Should "Mary Ann Smith" be broken up into Mary Ann" and "Smith" or "Mary" and "Ann Smith"?

Comment: @Servy, I can't make that up from the question. If there are more examples then I guess it would be better. But for now this should work.

Comment: @Habib He's asking how to properly parse a string with a name into a first and last name.  He said nothing about restricting it to just names with single work first and last names, or that he only has that one example to work with.  The problem is how to parse names unless other restrictions are specified.

Comment: @Servy, you are right with respect to multiple names, initially the question was asking about removing spaces. And answers were about using `string.Remove`. I replied with using `string.Split`. Now for multiple names and other formats, I am not sure, its not in the question and I am not sure if it is in the scope as well.

Comment: @Habib is there any limitation on the number of character the string can be split into?

Comment: @JohnRyann, I am not sure about any limit. `string.Split` returns a string array, and I guess you have to have a really large string to run out of memory .

Comment: @JohnRyann, Or you are talking about delimiters one can specify with `string.Split`, I am not sure about that either, `string.Split` does have param overload which receives characters, I am not sure about the limit, and I wouldn't be worried about it that much either

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method and use separator as `,`